# Do I need to issue CREATE INDEX everytime I update the database?

Tags: sql, database, sqlite, database-design

I have a geo-map database with columns of x,y,z,zoom and type. Initially the read speed is very slow when I use the call

```
SELECT image WHERE x = ... AND y=... AND zoom=... AND type =...
```

Thanks to the kind help from stack overflow, I found indexing of (x,y,z,zoom) has helped improved the read speed impressively.

However, I have a question this CREATE INDEX command only need to be issue once when the database initialize at the first time? And even the database grow up gradually, it will still enjoy the read speed improvement brought by indexing?

Or do I need to issue CREATE INDEX command every time before I close my application(during the application, the database will grow)?

Answer (score 5):

You will only need to create an index once.

The database will remember the columns with index and will keep changing the index along with your table.

If you insert an entry to the table, it will be added to the index. If you change an entry - it will be modified in the index. Finally, if you delete an entry - it will be removed from the index.

Note, the index will speed up your search operation - `SELECT` on the indexed columns, but will downgrade `INSERT`, `UPDATE`, `DELETE`.

Comment: Note however that to utilize the index for a specific query, statistics about tables and indexes are gathered and stored. If the data in the table and hence the index are changed a lot, you may have to refresh these statistics. You can use the command "analyze <tablename>; to do that. A second note: even if you have an index and the statistics are good, the query planner may decide not to use the index, because it found a more efficient execution path. And a third node: since you are dealing with spatial data, you may have a look at the spatialite extension.